# JsDocs: How do I use `@type` on class methods

Tags: javascript, class, methods, types, jsdoc

I was refactoring some code to use a class, rather than a static object.  And I discovered that all my jsDocs break.

I would like to label Class Methods with types the same way that I label Functions inside Objects.  Because it's rather prone to error to copy the same 6-line block to the top of each method, rather than 1-line.  Almost all the methods/functions in this class have the same signature.  I do not know how to make it reuse the one `@type` decorator.

```js
import { Request, Response, Handler } from "express";

const WorkingController = {
  /**
   * 
   * @param {Request} request 
   * @param {Response} response 
   * @param {Handler} next 
   */
  async getAll(request, response, next) {
    // intellisense works
  },

  /**@type {Handler}*/
  async get(request, response, next) {
    // intellisense works
    // and it's much slimmer
  }
}

class ControllerClass {
  /**@type {Handler}*/
  async getAll(request, response, next) {
    // !!!no intellisense!!!
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param {Request} request 
   * @param {Response} response 
   * @param {Handler} next 
   */
  async get(request, response, next) {
    // intellisense works
  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

For reference, I'm using vsCode version 1.47.1, without any jsdoc-specific extensions.